# How do I enter elements at specific indices in a Matlab array without a loop?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I delete the elements of an array `x` at certain indices.

```
x=rand(10,1);
delInd=[8 5];   
delInd=sort(delInd); %delInd must be sorted for this to work
x(delInd)=[];
```

Next, I calculate another array using `x`.

```
y=x+1;
```

Now, I would like to place new elements, say, `inf`, in `y` such that the new elements correspond to the positions of the deleted elements in the original `x`. I do this using the following code:

```
for ii=delInd'
   y=[y(1:ii-1);inf;y(ii:end)];
end
```

Can the above lines be vectorized and done without a `for` loop or without the sorting?

Comment: Instead of deleting the values first, you could set them to `Inf` directly.

Comment: Try `x(delInd)=inf`  should do what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace values in an array directly with values from another array by just using the indexes that you want to replace.

For example you could just replace the elements like this:

```
originalArr = 1:10;
replaceInd = [3 4 7 10];
replaceArr = [100 101 102 103];

originalArr(replaceInd) = replaceArr;
```

now the `originalArr` will contain

```
1 2 100 101 5 6 102 8 9 103
```

Comment: Actually, this is not my question. I am not replacing indices in the same array. I am replacing them in a different array of a shorter length, such that after they are placed, they will be in the same order of the initial array.

Comment: Hi @avgn Could you add an example with small arrays to your question?